# Sails.JS globals in React.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sails.js

I am having the following idea:

I want to display a bunch of [Card-Components](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/card/) from Reactstrap. Every of this Card-Components features another component which displays an progress bar to show the time to reload.
This works very well using an callback function to pass it to the child component which is triggered when the reload time is over.

Now I thought about how I can manage the data inside the Card-Component. The data is fetched from an third party API (simple JSON). I tried to implement this data-fetching logic in an [Sails.JS Helper](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/helpers).

But I am not able to call the global `sails` object from inside this component.
I enabled the `sails` object globally in `config/globals.js`:

```
/**
 * THIS FILE WAS ADDED AUTOMATICALLY by the Sails 1.0 app migration tool.
 * The original file was backed up as `config/globals-old.js.txt`
 */

 module.exports.globals = {
   _: require('lodash'),
   async: require('async'),
   models: true,
   sails: true
 };
```

So here is the Card-Component I am using:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Card, CardBody, CardImg, CardText, CardHeader, CardFooter } from 'reactstrap';
import { Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import { Progress } from 'reactstrap';
import ProgressBar from './ProgressBar';

class MyCard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log('Constructed card');
        this.state = {};
        this.progressUpdateCallback = this.progressUpdateCallback.bind(this);
        /*var sails = require(sails);*/
        this.thirdPartyInfo = sails.helpers.thirdPartyInfo();
    }

    progressUpdateCallback() {
        console.log('In callback');
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('Card component mounted');
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Col xs={1} sm={2} md={3} lg={4} className="mx-auto">
                <Card className="mt-4">
                    <CardHeader>
                        <Row>
                            <Col xs={2} sm={2} md={2} lg={2}>
                                <img src={this.props.cardLogo} 
                                    className="float-left img-fluid" />
                            </Col>
                            <Col className="text-left">
                                <strong>{this.props.headerText}</strong>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </CardHeader>
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardText>{this.props.text}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                    <CardFooter>
                        <ProgressBar parentUpdateMillis={this.props.updateAfterSeconds * 1000} updateMillis="1000" callback={this.progressUpdateCallback} />
                    </CardFooter>
                </Card>
            </Col>
        );
    };
}

export default MyCard;
```

My ProgressBar component looks like:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Progress } from 'reactstrap';

class ProgressBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            reloadedCounter: 0,
            currentProgBarPercent: 0
        };
        this.updateProgBar = this.updateProgBar.bind(this);
    }

    updateProgBar() {
        if(this.state.currentProgBarPercent == 100) {
            if(typeof(this.props.callback) === 'function') {
                this.props.callback();
            }
            this.setState({
                reloadedCounter: 0,
                currentProgBarPercent: 0
            });

        } else {
            this.setState({
                reloadedCounter: this.state.reloadedCounter + 1,
                currentProgBarPercent: (this.state.reloadedCounter + 1) * (100 / (this.props.parentUpdateMillis / this.props.updateMillis))
            });
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(this.updateProgBar, this.props.updateMillis);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Progress value={this.state.currentProgBarPercent} />
            </div>
        );
    };
}

export default ProgressBar;
```

And my helper:

```
var sprintf = require("sprintf-js").sprintf;

module.exports = {
  friendlyName: 'Some info',
  description: 'Returns some info',

  inputs: {
    what: {
      type: 'string',
      example: 'currentTime',
      description: 'Fetch with information',
      required: true
    }
  },

  exits: {
    success: {
      outPutFriendlyName: 'Information',
      outputDescription: 'TODO: Explain and define the model to return the data'
    },

    infoNotFound: {
      description: 'Could not find the given type of information'
    }  
  },

  fn: function (inputs, exits) {
    var apiURL = sprintf('https://3rdPartySite/v1/%s', inputs.what);
    console.log('Using %s for fetching data from 3rdPartySite', apiURL);

    fetch(apiURL).then( results => {
      return results.json();
    }).then(data => {
      console.log('Info result: %j', data.results);
    });

    // All done.
    return exits.success();
  }
};
```

But after lifting up that hole thing I get the following displayed in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: sails is not defined
```

I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the `sails` object inside the react component , because the code of your components get executed on the client side, the `sails` object is globally accessible on the server side of your application.

Comment: Ah okay. Got it. What do you think is the best way to implement this communication. I am thinking about an action2 and a route

Comment: Yes you can create a route mapped to an action which grabs the data you need and then you send the response to the react component, you can call the endpoint from `componentDidMount` which is the best place to fetch data.